# C#: Long Path with UseLegacyPathHandling and BlockLongPaths not working

Tags: c#, pathtoolongexception

I'm using C# with .NET v4.7.2 and Windows 10 and I have some files with long path (>260 characters in the paths) to copy.

I know there is a solution to prefix the path by `\\?\`

This prefix is working, but I do not want to prefix everytime for any file operation. since .Net v4.6.2 there is be a better solution by AppContext-Switches `UseLegacyPathHandling` and `BlockLongPaths`.

However this is not working.

My `app.config` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2"/>
  </startup>
  <windowsSettings>
    <longPathAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">true</longPathAware>
  </windowsSettings>
  <runtime>
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling=false;Switch.System.IO.BlockLongPaths=false" />
  </runtime> 
</configuration>
```

My C# looks like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string src = @"c:\Temp\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.txt";
   string dst = @"c:\Temp\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-123.txt";
   File.Copy(src, dst);
}
```

**My Problem**

- With .NET v4.5, `File.Copy()` throws a `System.IO.PathTooLongException`
- With .NET v4.7.2 `File.Copy()` throws a `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException`

I checked by `AppContext.TryGetSwitch()` if the switches are set, and they are. So I don't know how to get I to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You also have to convince the operating system that your program can handle long paths.  That's done with the windowsSettings element, but it is in the wrong place.  Not in the .config file, it belongs in the application manifest.  If you don't already have one then use Project > Add New Item > Application Manifest File.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/

Comment: thank you for your input - I'll going to try that.

Answer (score 2):

Your filename is 317 characters long, which exceeds the 255 characters allowed in an NTFS path segment ([#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3406521/70345), [#2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/#comment-935)).

(In retrospect, it was probably a mistake for Jeremy to use an example that couldn't possibly work on any filesystem in #2!)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So the really only way in a filesystem to have filenames longer than 255 is to prefix it with "\\?\"    ???

Comment: Refer to the comment from @hans-passant to get an idea of how this can be done on Win10.